# Given an iterable, how to apply a function in every possible combination?

Tags: python

Given the iterable `[A, B, C]` and the function `f(x)` I want to get the following:

```
[  A,     B,     C]  
[  A,     B,   f(C)]  
[  A,   f(B),    C]
[  A,   f(B),  f(C)]
[f(A),    B,     C]
[f(A),    B,   f(C)]
[f(A),  f(B),    C]
[f(A),  f(B),  f(C)]
```

Unfortunately I didn't find anything suitable in the itertools module.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> L = ["A", "B", "C"]
>>> def f(c): return c.lower()
... 
>>> fL = [f(x) for x in L]
>>> for i in product(*zip(L, fL)):
...     print i
... 
('A', 'B', 'C')
('A', 'B', 'c')
('A', 'b', 'C')
('A', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'B', 'C')
('a', 'B', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'C')
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Explanation:

Call `f` for each item in `L` to generate `fL`

```
>>> fL
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Use `zip` to zip the two lists into pairs

```
>>> zip(L, fL)
[('A', 'a'), ('B', 'b'), ('C', 'c')]
```

Take the cartesian product of those tuples using `itertools.product`

```
product(*zip(L, fL))
```

is equivalent to

```
product(*[('A', 'a'), ('B', 'b'), ('C', 'c')])
```

and that is equivalent to

```
product(('A', 'a'), ('B', 'b'), ('C', 'c'))
```

looping over that product, gives exactly the result we need.

Comment: This works, but it computes `f` a lot more than necessary, which could be a problem depending on how expensive `f` is.

Comment: Accepted your answer for the second solution. I believe it makes much more sense from the logical perspective as well. Would be cool if you edit your answer to have only the latter solution with deeper description.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), like this

```
def f(char):
    return char.lower()

iterable = ["A", "B", "C"]
indices = range(len(iterable))
from itertools import combinations
for i in range(len(iterable) + 1):
    for items in combinations(indices, i):
        print [f(iterable[j]) if j in items else iterable[j] for j in range(len(iterable))]
```

**Output**

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
['a', 'B', 'C']
['A', 'b', 'C']
['A', 'B', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'C']
['a', 'B', 'c']
['A', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: The output should contain all elements from the input, i.e.: ['a', 'B', 'C'], not just ['a'].

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
def func_combinations(f, l):
    return itertools.product(*zip(l, map(f, l)))
```

Demo:

```
>>> for combo in func_combinations(str, range(3)):
...     print combo
...
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, '2')
(0, '1', 2)
(0, '1', '2')
('0', 1, 2)
('0', 1, '2')
('0', '1', 2)
('0', '1', '2')
```

This function first computes `f` once for every element of the input. Then, it uses `zip` to turn the input and the list of `f` values into a list of input-output pairs. Finally, it uses `itertools.product` to produce each possible way to select either input or output.